# Ignore DST (Dayligt Saving Time) while formating date

Tags: java, android, date

I have this application which compares current date to a parsed date from an xml file:

```
Date timeDiff = new Date(date.getTime() - new Date().getTime());
```

The problem is when i output the variable timeDiff as a string via simpleDateFormat, daylight saving time is taken to account which adds an extra hour. This messes up my output.

Is there anyway to make SimpleDateFormat ignore DST?

Thanks!

Comment: [Duration is not the same as Date-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397531/10819573)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys! Maybe better with this solution:

```
public static String millisToString(long l){
        long h, m;
        h = l / 3600000;
        m = (l % 3600000) / 60000;
        if(h == 0){
            return m + "m";
        }else{
            return h + "h " + m + "m";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're subtracting one time from another, to get a duration in milliseconds. You shouldn't be trying to format that as a *date* at all. It's a number of milliseconds, not a date.

It's not clear what you *expect* the result to be, but at the moment you're basically going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Well im trying to output the milliseconds as a string, for example: if timeDiff.getTime() is 4500000 i want to output 1h 15m:
 new SimpleDateFormat("H'h' m'm'").format(timeDiff)

Comment: @Richard: I'd normally suggest using Joda Time for this (http://joda-time.sf.net) but that *might* be a bit big for your Android app. Have you considered just splitting it into hours, minutes, seconds in code and then just using string formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html).
It has the [normalize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#normalize%28boolean%29) method that takes a boolean to indicate if you want to ignore DST.