# How to convert String time to Long milliseconds in Java

Tags: java, java-time, duration

I'm trying to convert a time string to milliseconds using the code below. Because I will use the time as countdown timer.

The problem is that the time is from database and it is on varchar type. I tried this code and it's not giving me the correct output.

```
String timeDuration = "10:00"; //for example only
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
Date time = sdf.parse(timeDuration);
long millis = time.getTime(); //The output must be 600000
```

I'm getting the wrong "millis" using this code.

I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Split at `:`, create an `int` from both values, multiple the left one by 60, add it to the right one, then multiply everything by 1000.

Comment: The output is `600000` for me.

Comment: Do it as @luk2302 said or build a `java.time.Duration` from the results of the split operation and call `.toMillis()` on that duration object.

Comment: @luk2302 you got it right thanks dude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Duration is not the same as Date-Time

Duration is not the same as Date-Time and therefore you should not parse your string into a Date-Time type. The Date-Time type (e.g. `java.util.Date`) represents a point in time whereas a duration represents a length of time. You can understand it from the following examples:

1. I have been reading this book **for** 10 minutes.
2. I have been reading this book **since** 4:00 pm.

The first example has a duration whereas the second example has a Date-Time (implicitly today).

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

You can convert your string into [ISO 8601 format for a Duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and then parse the resulting string into [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which you can be converted into milliseconds.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(durationToMillis("10:00"));
    }

    static long durationToMillis(String strDuration) {
        String[] arr = strDuration.split(":");
        Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;
        if (arr.length == 2) {
            strDuration = "PT" + arr[0] + "M" + arr[1] + "S";
            duration = Duration.parse(strDuration);
        }
        return duration.toMillis();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
600000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lpDQC0)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Well explained difference

Answer (score 2):

Using classes SimpleDateFormat and Date is **VERY STRONGLY** discouraged. These classes are deprecated and very problematic. Use package java.time instead. for parser use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Also, in your case you may use class [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Alternatively, you can use Open Source MgntUtils library That has class [TimeInterval](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/entities/TimeInterval.html) and method [TextUtils.parseStringToTimeInterval(java.lang.String valueStr)](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#parseStringToTimeInterval-java.lang.String-). In this case your code could be very simple:

```
long milliseconds = TextUtils.parseStringToTimeInterval("10m").toMillis();
```

And this will give you 600000 as a result. The library is available as Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils), and on the github (including source code and Javadoc) [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Here is a link to [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/). The article about the library is [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) (See paragraph "Parsing String to Time Interval")

**Disclaimer**: The library is written by me

Answer (score -5):

I think you can cut substring first. Then convert the substring to integer. Then multiple with 60000.

```
Integer.parseInt(timeDuration.substring(0, timeDuration.indexOf(":"))) * 60 * 1000
```

HTH

Cheers,

Hook