# Convert time in minutes to HH:mm in java 11

Tags: java, timezone

I am receiving a json payload which has the time in minutes, I need to convert it to HH:mm and may even require to set the time zone also,

I tried this solution

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    
    try {
        Date dt = sdf.parse("90");
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So there any simplified way to do this

Comment: Please have a look at the "new" DateTime API (the classes in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package). `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date` should no longer be used in new code. Specifically, the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) will be interesting for you.

Comment: However, if we are talking about a duration and not a time, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800301/2513200) shows several ways to do this, probably the best way would be to use `Duration` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenient methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minutes = 123;
        Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes);

        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%d:%02d", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT2H3M
2:03
2:03
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/hcRqsk)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

When you say 123 minutes, it is independent of timezone i.e. duration of 123 minutes will have the same value in any timezone. Check [Duration is not the same as Date-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397531/10819573) to understand the difference between a Date-Time and a Duration. In layman's terms, a Date-Time is like a vector quantity while Duration is like a scalar quantity.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation,I wanted to change the time zone also

Comment: @Thejas - When you say 123 minutes, it is independent of timezone i.e. a duration of 123 minutes will have the same value in any timezone. Check [Duration is not the same as Date-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397531/10819573) to understand the difference between a Date-Time and a Duration. In layman's terms, a Date-Time is like a vector quantity while Duration is like a scalar quantity.